# How to get the current position of a container

Tags: jquery

I intend to add a class slide to my section as soon as I scroll to that section using this code:

```
//getting the current position of an element
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(y);

  //getting the location of the animation container
  var container_pos = $('.animation_container').position();

  var container_height  = $('.animation_container').height();

  if( y >= (container_pos.top - container_height - 100)){
    $('section#our_menu > section').addClass('slide');
  }
});
```

When scrolling I wanna be able to add the slide class shortly after I start seeing the section I want to add the slide class.

At the moment, I can add the slide class but it happens waay after I pass its  container.
For that I used the following code but as much as I change the 100 value to another am not really getting it right:

```
if( y >= (container_pos.top - container_height - 100)){
```

My box mockup looks like this:

```
<section id="our_menu" class="animation container">
  <section>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Is there anything am doing wrong?

Comment: try to use `offset()` instead of `position()`. Maybe `offsetParent()` is  better, when you scroll your container and not your body.

Comment: I added offset but it only adds the class when I pass the section

Comment: you may take the screen height using `$(window).height()` and substract half of it from the position.